# Why Bloom filters cannot handle range queries?

Tags: bloom-filter, rocksdb, lsm-tree

Context: I'm reading about RocksDB and LSM trees, from my understanding Bloom filter is used to avoid multiple I/Os for item retrieval in all the storage levels. And I'm ok with that.

Apparently, one of the challenges is that Bloom filter **cannot** be used in range queries. What is the reason? If I want to check if there is a key between 32 and 200, I can do a single-key lookup for each value in between (or stop at the first "true" response). Is it really inefficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that but it is inefficient because single point lookup are slow (even with bloom filters) comparing to seeking the first value (32) and iterating towards 200. Leveldb/rocksdb are optimized for such iterations.

Furthermore in your case you just want any first key between 32 and 200 - you just do one seek and that's it while otherwise you'd have to do in worst case 200-32 = 168 lookups. Bloom filter can quickly answer whether the key is not present if there are no collisions, but it still requires a disk lookup if there is.

Comment: for future reference, 
you may want to take a look at SuRF.  It won the best paper at SIGMOD this year.
http://www.pdl.cmu.edu/PDL-FTP/Storage/surf_sigmod18.pdf

It is a filter that supports range queries, and was tested in RocksDB.

Comment: I am still lost without modifying BF its not possible to do range queries, is there any trick that RocksDB implemented?